# sending email in asp.net sends password instead of email

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to send email after user has been registered successfully. but it sends password in FROM section instead of sending email like abc@gmail.com here it sends 1234kjfh. what am I missing here?

```
string name=txtfirstname.Text;
string fileName = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/TextFile.txt");
string mailBody = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Name##", txtfirstname.Text);
mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Email##", email);
mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Phone##", txtphone.Text);
MailMessage myMessage = new MailMessage();
myMessage.Subject = "Re: Activate your account for AIS FORUM";
myMessage.Body = mailBody;
myMessage.From = new MailAddress("abc@gmail.com", "1234kjfh");
myMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(txtemail.Text, email));
SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
mySmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;  
mySmtpClient.Send(myMessage);
```

Plz help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missing something here

new MailAddress(address, displayName)

so, you have added display name as "1234kjfh"

Update your code as follow.

```
string name=txtfirstname.Text;
        string fileName = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/TextFile.txt");
        string mailBody = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Name##", txtfirstname.Text);
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Email##", email);
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Phone##", txtphone.Text);
        MailMessage myMessage = new MailMessage();
        myMessage.Subject = "Re: Activate your account for AIS FORUM";
        myMessage.Body = mailBody;
        myMessage.From = new MailAddress("abc@gmail.com", "abc@gmail.com");
        myMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(txtemail.Text, email));
        SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        mySmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;  
        mySmtpClient.Send(myMessage);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

The second parameter of the [constructor of `MailAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s17zfkf(v=vs.110).aspx) is `displayName`. You aren't setting the credentials used to send the mail, you are setting the display name.

To set the credentials, use [`SmtpClient.Credentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.credentials(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server, port);
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

Comment: You would receive a lot of downvotes, but the TL;DR version of your answer should be: **RTFM**!